# What is this control called and does it exist in Windows? (Control from iTunes/Mac)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-controls

[image]

If you've never used iTunes, what this basically is like a vertical listbox with images instead of text, so you select one of them and it changes something. I was wondering:

1. What is this called
2. Does it exist in .NET or do I have to create my own?

EDIT: I'd prefer for it to exist in WinForms but tell me if it exists in WPF as well

Comment: That's just a bunch of four buttons that render in a grouped way, it's not a special control. The equivalent Windows controls would be four toolbar buttons, using a separator between the groups.

Comment: They arent buttons, if anything they are closer to a listbox or checkboxes, and does .NET come with this or do I half to make it myself?

Comment: You can make anything you want in WPF without much effort - just use a listbox with an itemtemplate and you are sorted!

Comment: @leaf68 They're a group of radio buttons, rendered as togglable toolbar buttons. Or a group of toolbar buttons, coded to have the behaviour of a group of radio buttons. (For what it's worth, checkboxes are also a type of button in WPF.) Not every possible combination of visual appearance and behaviour has its own control.

Answer (score 0):

The only similar control I know is `FlowDocumentReader` from WPF:

[image: FlowDocumentReader example]

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).